# Get space between floating divs using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an layout using bootstrap with multiple floating `divs`.

I want to retrieve the space between the `divs` using `JavaScript`. Ive only no idea how i can do this. See below picture.

> **A picture says  a 1000 words ;)**
>
> [image: Blockquote]

Ive created a fiddle with above layout, i will paste it here so you can play with it if you want.

```css
.page-container {
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.column {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
}

[class^="col-"] {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="page-container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="column">
            <h2>
        Floating element #1
        </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus ullamcorper commodo. Donec volutpat porttitor elit sit amet aliquet. Nam eget felis vel sapien tempus tincidunt placerat ac lectus. Donec malesuada, est ac accumsan porta, leo augue varius ante, ut cursus tortor mauris non ipsum. Vestibulum nec odio diam. Integer gravida varius risus quis euismod. Donec iaculis velit vitae semper bibendum. Donec et volutpat ligula. Sed in elit et risus facilisis maximus. Cras tempor sollicitudin velit, a mattis elit molestie non. Maecenas vitae eros in leo feugiat maximus at porttitor mauris. Vivamus vulputate tellus laoreet neque vulputate suscipit sit amet eget ipsum. Donec faucibus dignissim erat, at bibendum dui laoreet eget.
        </p>
        <p>
        Curabitur quam sapien, lacinia sit amet sagittis sed, fringilla nec arcu. Morbi at velit facilisis, aliquet justo non, tincidunt mauris. Curabitur tempus ante sit amet auctor fringilla. Sed ut velit ac purus euismod placerat. Fusce ultrices feugiat tortor at condimentum. Ut eleifend eget velit at vulputate. In commodo ligula et urna ultrices, non ullamcorper est pharetra. Donec pharetra, purus a aliquam rutrum, lacus arcu porttitor nunc, eu maximus eros justo sed neque. Fusce a urna non enim lobortis venenatis. Suspendisse potenti.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="column">
            <h2>
        Floating element #2
        </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus ullamcorper commodo. Donec volutpat porttitor elit sit amet aliquet. Nam eget felis vel sapien tempus tincidunt placerat ac lectus. Donec malesuada, est ac accumsan porta, leo augue varius ante, ut cursus tortor mauris non ipsum. Vestibulum nec odio diam. Integer gravida varius risus quis euismod. Donec iaculis velit vitae semper bibendum. Donec et volutpat ligula. Sed in elit et risus facilisis maximus. Cras tempor sollicitudin velit, a mattis elit molestie non. Maecenas vitae eros in leo feugiat maximus at porttitor mauris. Vivamus vulputate tellus laoreet neque vulputate suscipit sit amet eget ipsum. Donec faucibus dignissim erat, at bibendum dui laoreet eget.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
       <div class="column">
        <h2>
        Floating element #3
        </h2>
        <p>
            Curabitur quam sapien, lacinia sit amet sagittis sed, fringilla nec arcu. Morbi at velit facilisis, aliquet justo non, tincidunt mauris. Curabitur tempus ante sit amet auctor fringilla. Sed ut velit ac purus euismod placerat. Fusce ultrices feugiat tortor at condimentum. Ut eleifend eget velit at vulputate. In commodo ligula et urna ultrices, non ullamcorper est pharetra. Donec pharetra, purus a aliquam rutrum, lacus arcu porttitor nunc, eu maximus eros justo sed neque. Fusce a urna non enim lobortis venenatis. Suspendisse potenti.
        </p>
        <p>
        Fusce a velit et justo porttitor sollicitudin a a velit. Praesent ultrices arcu a sodales ultricies. Etiam cursus mattis dapibus. Fusce vulputate commodo pretium. Suspendisse a orci vitae ipsum interdum dapibus a quis velit. Proin euismod, lectus id euismod semper, tellus nunc luctus dui, consectetur venenatis erat mi eu dolor. Nunc eleifend semper lacus, at hendrerit massa. Praesent ac magna at lacus commodo faucibus eu sit amet magna. Donec pellentesque felis et leo interdum dignissim. Sed sit amet sapien ac quam auctor semper quis ut nibh. Vivamus consectetur, ipsum luctus semper viverra, sem arcu sagittis mauris, a interdum odio sapien in augue.
        </p>
        <p>
        Nam ut bibendum urna, sed congue neque. Nunc a nunc venenatis, porttitor odio vitae, finibus est. Suspendisse quis purus a diam aliquam ullamcorper eu sed dolor. Etiam ac eros eget nisl pretium lobortis. Nulla convallis id nunc eget efficitur. Morbi vel elementum justo. Phasellus et egestas quam. Cras eu tristique urna. Cras ac justo efficitur, consectetur eros et, tincidunt nulla. Quisque et cursus ipsum. Ut tincidunt, purus et tempor fermentum, nulla diam suscipit ex, non sodales eros nunc vel ante. Duis quis justo quam. Sed imperdiet lorem et blandit pretium. Etiam elit dui, tristique et vehicula vitae, venenatis et augue.
        </p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="column">
        <h2>
        Floating element #4
        </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus ullamcorper commodo. Donec volutpat porttitor elit sit amet aliquet. Nam eget felis vel sapien tempus tincidunt placerat ac lectus. Donec malesuada, est ac accumsan porta, leo augue varius ante, ut cursus tortor mauris non ipsum. Vestibulum nec odio diam. Integer gravida varius risus quis euismod. Donec iaculis velit vitae semper bibendum. Donec et volutpat ligula. Sed in elit et risus facilisis maximus. Cras tempor sollicitudin velit, a mattis elit molestie non. Maecenas vitae eros in leo feugiat maximus at porttitor mauris. Vivamus vulputate tellus laoreet neque vulputate suscipit sit amet eget ipsum. Donec faucibus dignissim erat, at bibendum dui laoreet eget.
        </p>
        <p>
        Curabitur quam sapien, lacinia sit amet sagittis sed, fringilla nec arcu. Morbi at velit facilisis, aliquet justo non, tincidunt mauris. Curabitur tempus ante sit amet auctor fringilla. Sed ut velit ac purus euismod placerat. Fusce ultrices feugiat tortor at condimentum. Ut eleifend eget velit at vulputate. In commodo ligula et urna ultrices, non ullamcorper est pharetra. Donec pharetra, purus a aliquam rutrum, lacus arcu porttitor nunc, eu maximus eros justo sed neque. Fusce a urna non enim lobortis venenatis. Suspendisse potenti.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="column">
        <h2>
        Floating element #4
        </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus ullamcorper commodo. Donec volutpat porttitor elit sit amet aliquet. Nam eget felis vel sapien tempus tincidunt placerat ac lectus. Donec malesuada, est ac accumsan porta, leo augue varius ante, ut cursus tortor mauris non ipsum. Vestibulum nec odio diam. Integer gravida varius risus quis euismod. Donec iaculis velit vitae semper bibendum. Donec et volutpat ligula. Sed in elit et risus facilisis maximus. Cras tempor sollicitudin velit, a mattis elit molestie non. Maecenas vitae eros in leo feugiat maximus at porttitor mauris. Vivamus vulputate tellus laoreet neque vulputate suscipit sit amet eget ipsum. Donec faucibus dignissim erat, at bibendum dui laoreet eget.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Im trying to get those pixel, and move the underlying `div` up using `JavaScript`. I know i can use something like `masonry`. But i can't get those working in my application.

Does anyone have an idea how i can do this? (oh, using `jQuery` is no problem)

Comment: _“Does anyone have an idea how i can do this?”_ - how could anyone who ever had basic math in school _not_ have one? How to get an element’s position and measures is trivial enough to research ... so what exactly are you still missing?

Comment: I just dont know how to do it. I need a starting point.

Comment: This should give you - `const space = bottomElementOffsetFromTop - (firstElementOffsetFromTop + firstElementHeight)`

Comment: You can try to add the top offset and the height of the top column, and subtract the top offset of the bottom column from that.
You can Google how to obtain each of those values.

Comment: Top position of second element minus (top position of first element plus height of first element) equals …?

Comment: maybe it's something like:  (height of "Floating element #3" - (height of "Floating element #1" - height of "Floating element #2"))


To get the height: var result = $("#divID").height();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of:

```
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').clientHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').offsetHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('someDiv').scrollHeight;
```

`clientHeigh`t includes the height and vertical padding.

`offsetHeight` includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

`scrollHeight` includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.

with JQuery

```
$('#someDiv').height();
$('#someDiv').width();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the direction. I used this in my final solution. With the help of google and so ive managed to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get first element's x,y cordinates (e.g [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element))
2. Get first elements height and width (e.g. marco gomes answer)
3. Get fourth element's x,y cordinates
4. Calculate:
   **Fourth's x pos minus (First's x pos + height) = empty space's height**
   As it is same width as other's width, you have a width.

If you need dynamically find gaps, you can loop all divs and put them in column groups (with help of x pos). Then you do above for each group's current and next in order element (they **should** be in right order). If the vertical difference is above set rule, you can assume you have a gap.